# VBA looping through each file in folder

Tags: excel, vba

I know similar questions have been asked, but I've tried all the solution codes with no success. I'm a beginner in VBA and What I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. Copy files from sfol to dfol
2. For each file now in dfol, if "summary" tab exists, change cell I3
3. For each file in dfol, if "sheet2" tab exists, change pivot filter

The code runs and the changes are complete for the first file in dfol, but it doesn't even open each of the rest of the files. I need it to open every file. Also as a side note, the final msgbox at the end does not pop-up, so I'm thinking the code doesn't even run its full course.

```
Sub GenerateReports()

'Generate Seed Run Validation Reports Macro

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim MainFile, dfol, sfol As String
Dim vDate, Fname, myExtension As String
Dim wsCount As Integer
Dim fso

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Confirm the user wants to proceed
    If MsgBox("Compile?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

'Define current workbook
    MainFile = ThisWorkbook.Name

'Define Dates
    vDate = "Potato"

'Set file path
    sfol = "I:\ABCFolder"
    dfol = "I:\DEFFolder"

'Copy all files from source folder
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fso.CopyFolder sfol, dfol

'Target Path with extension
    myExtension = "*.xls*"
    dfol = dfol & "\"
    Fname = Dir(dfol & myExtension)

'Loop through files in folder
    Do While Fname <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=dfol & Fname)

        'Ensure workbook opened
        DoEvents

        wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count

        For i = 1 To wsCount
            'Update Date on Summary tab
            If wb.Worksheets(i).Name = "Summary" Then
                wb.Worksheets(i).Range("I3") = vDate
            End If
        Next i

        'save changes and close
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

        'Ensure workbook closed
        DoEvents

        'Get next file name
        Fname = Dir

    Loop

'***************************** End of Macro ***************************
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
MsgBox ("Assumptions Compiled!")
End Sub
```

Additional problems:

1. Every time a file is opened, I get asked if I want to update the links. I need it just not update.
2. I will also need to rename all the files in the folder starting with "2017..." to be, say, "2018..."

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify not to update links when opening.

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=dfol & Fname, UpdateLinks:=false)
```

Use SaveAs to change the name of the open workbook.

```
wb.saveas FileName:=replace(wb.name, "2017", "2018")
```

After the SaveAs, `wb` will be the new copy of the original.

Use `on error resume next` for a more direct route to changing data on the Summary worksheet.

```
on error resume next
with wb.worksheets("summary")
     .Range("I3") = vDate
end with
on error goto 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the file dir. It looks OK but I will test further.

Comment: going back to the SaveAs, how can I specify that it be saved in dfol? What you mentioned worked great for renaming, but it was saved to a random folder.

Comment: If *2017* is not part of the path then use `wb.fullname` instead but it may be better as `FileName:=dfol & replace(wb.name, "2017", "2018")` just in case 2017 is part of the path.